# Combine each column from 2 different table into one table

Tags: sql

I want to combine these table column into one table

table 1

```
account_number currentAddress   
CCA2312311     Address1   
CCA2312311     Address2
```

table 2

```
account_number proposedAddress
  CCA2312311     Address1
  CCA2312311     Address2
  CCA2312311     Address3
```

the result should be

```
account_number  currentAddress proposedADdress
CCA2312311       Address1       Address1
CCA2312311       Address2       Address2
CCA2312311       Null           Address3
```

Comment: Sounds pretty straightforward. What have you tried for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select t2.account_number,t2.proposedaddress, t1.currentaddress
From table2 t2 left outer join table1 t1 on    
(t1.account_number=t2.account_number and   
Upper(Trim(t1.currentaddress)) like Upper(Trim(t2.proposedaddress)))
```

Comment: the query gives me only two results. not the result i mentioned above

Comment: Try this. I created tables as yours and fill your data. This and previous queries gives me result what you want.  What is your rdbms name? I use oracle sql.

Comment: I just tried your given example still give me a null account_number

Comment: I added account_number column to select list. Try again please.

Comment: I am glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple right join will do. (Do note that right join returns all the table on the right as i assume that is what you want). If you want to return account_number that has both currentAddress and ProposedAddress (Use innerjoin)

```
select A. CurrentAddress, 
       B. ProposedAddress 
from [table 1] A --please note that for table names, best not to have space   
right join [table 2] B 
on A. account_number = B. account_number
```

Please find this link helpful: http://www.sql-join.com/sql-join-types/